# Unable to Annotate greyed out and 'Editor inline blame' not working for specific directory (/test)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm working on a project, where I need to continuously see, who wrote code, to see if it needs to be update or not. The "editor inline blame"-feature I've had working for a long time.

But in my `tests/e2e`-folder, then all files in there doesn't show me the "editor inline blame". It looks like this:

[image: No inline blame]

I expected it to look like this:

[image: Inline blame working]

In the `tests/e2e`-folder I can't right-click the sidebar at choose 'Annotate' either:

And I can't right-click in the sidebar and click 'Annotate' either:

[image: Annotate not working]

I expected this:

[image: Annotate working]

This is the same for all files inside my: `test/e2e`-folder. How do I get the Editor Inline Blame to be shown?

---

### Solution attempt 1: Update PhpStorm

I updated from v2022.x.x to this:

> PhpStorm 2023.2.4
> Build #PS-232.10227.13, built on November 18, 2023
> macOS 14.0
> Memory: 4096M
>
> Non-Bundled Plugins:
> com.4lex4.intellij.solarized (2.4.0)
> IdeaVIM (2.7.5)
> dev.meanmail.plugin.nginx-intellij-plugin (2022.1.1)
> ru.adelf.idea.dotenv (2023.2)
> com.dmarcotte.handlebars (232.8660.88)
> zielu.gittoolbox (500.0.23+222)
> mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore (4.5.2)

No change.

---

### Solution attempt 2: Reinstall the GitToolbox-plugin

I think this is offered by the [GitToolbox-plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox). So I removed that completely and installed it anew.

No change.

---

### Solution attempt 3: Invalidate all caches

Went to "File" >> "Invalidate caches" and checked everything. And then restarted PhpStorm.

No change.

---

### Solution attempt 4: Consider if the `test`-directory is special

I tried right-clicking and looking at options. But I can't find anything on there, that can 'mark it as irrelevant for Git' or anything.

The closest thing I found was this:

[image: Right click my test-directory]

But that didn't change anything either.

[image: Annotate not possible]

Answer (score 0):

In directory mappings, do you have your project mapped to exact path?

How many repos are you opening?

Can you disable all non-bundled plugins and try?

Also, it's best to contact JetBrains support with issues reproduced and logs attached.